# How to debug 3rd party application and see what happens upon button click?

Tags: debugging, dll, reverse-engineering

I am trying to determine what a 3rd party app does when I click certain button. 
App is probably writen in C++.

Also I'm guessing that all code that is executed upon the button click is stored in separated dll file and not in the main exe. This guess is made on what happens when you click the button and name of a certain dll file.
I examined this dll and it has three extern(public) functions.

I want two things:

1. How to set breakpoint to catch button click event, if it's even possible?
2. How to detect when the three extern functions from dll get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spy++ to find tin wndprocs handling the messages for the buttons you interested in, then use a debugger such as ollydbg to conditionally breakpoint the proc for the button clicked message id. From there its just about tracing through the code. To catch those dll functions, just set breakpoints on them inside the dll that contains them, else if you want to catch it from a specific module, just breakpoint the jump entry in the IAT(under olly you can view all imported/exported symbols using ctrl + n)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm doing some progress now.